# showPopup() vs showDialog()

Tags: java, android, optionmenu

`mainMenuButton` is an `ImageButton` on the left side of the `Toolbar` that displays a `ContextMenu` when clicked. Why is the `ContextMenu` displayed as a Dialog when I short-click and a Popup when I long-click? More specifically, why is `showPopup` called in one case and `showDialog` called in the other in the `ContextMenuBuilder` class?

This is where I set up `mainMenuButton` in `HomeScreen.java` in `onCreate()`:

```
mainMenuButton = myToolbar.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button);
mainMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.showContextMenu();
    }
});
registerForContextMenu(mainMenuButton);
```

**onCreateContextMenu()**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
}
```